# Input.Java.Mismatch error: Null for text file

Tags: java, file, text

So I looked at other answers and I did not find a solution to my question.
I'm new to Java so don't expect complex methods, I'll show what's in the text file and a few methods, thanks :)
By the way, it's a runtime error.

Text File:

```
1.1206060982385907E-23 
1.8211358653686147E-24 
1.6396713341496784E-24 
5.76142040175542E-24 
1.305001288660403E-26
1.8362146624686452E-26
1.0207894499723824E-25
1.0867598055339296E-25 
4.670786575865269E-23
```

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    // Extension idea... instead of hard codeing the weight, you may propt the user for input.
    // Initialize Variables
    double[] gravity = new double[9];
    File fileRead = new File("/Users/jerome/Desktop/Gravity.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (fileRead); 
    for (int i = 0; i<9; i ++)
    {
      gravity[i] = inFile.nextDouble(); // Fails here

    }
    inFile.close();
    double earthWeight = 100.0; // initalize Earth weight to 100 lbs.
    String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
    // Processing
    double[] weights = calcWeight(earthWeight, gravity);  // static method you write

    // Output
    printResults(names, gravity, weights);


} //end main
}//end class
```

Printing to Screen:

```
public static void printResults(String[] name,double gravity[],double weights[])
{
        System.out.printf("%25s %n","My Weight on the Planets");
        System.out.printf("%10s %13s %13s %n"," Planet","Gravity","Weight (lbs)");
        System.out.printf("%s %n","================================================");
        for (int i = 0; i<9; i ++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%10s %13s %13s %16s %n",name[i],gravity[i],weights[i]);
        }
}
```

Gravity calculation:

```
public static double[] calcWeight(double earthWeight,double[] gravity)
{
        double[] calcWeight = new double[9];

        for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            calcWeight[i] = earthWeight * gravity[i];
        }
        return calcWeight;
}
```

Comment: You should show, the Exception Trace also.

Comment: Put ** around the error

Comment: Try this `String gravity = scanner.next(); System.out.println(gravity); gravity[i] = Double.parseDouble(gravity)` Does the code fail at `Double.parseDouble`? Also for the error above can you put the full exception trace you get when running, ie. all the output?

Comment: Yeah I think it would fail at Double.parseDouble